# Can't drag and drop text in gedit

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, gedit, drag-and-drop

I've installed gnome-shell on Ubuntu 11.10 but now, when I'm on Unity, and when I drag and drop text in gedit, gedit crashes ! 
I've tried to uninstall gnome-shell, but nothing changes.

Comment: Could you start gedit from the terminal and do what causes it to crash and then include the terminal output in your question?

Comment: This should probably be a bug report. Off-topic on Ask Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just reading the Gnome 3.2.2 release notes and came accross this:

```
===========
gedit 3.2.3
===========
New Features and Fixes
======================
- Fix crash when dropping file in gedit with snippets plugin active (Paolo Borelli)
```

Maybe this is somehow related. It's worth a try to disable the snippets plugin (or update to 3.2.3).

Comment: So, I disabled some gedit's plugins and it works again ! But I don't know which plugin(s) make gedit crashes ... Thank you ! (Sorry for my bad english :)